# OutlinedBox TextInputLayout and gravity center?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

How to achieve centered new **OutlinedBox** style with **TextInputLayout**?

Current behavior:

[image: left and center]

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>     android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
>     style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:gravity="left"
>     >
>     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="left"
>         android:hint="hint"
>         />
> </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
>
> <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>     android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
>     style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     >
>     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:hint="hint2"
>         />
> </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
> ```

I use `com.android.support:design:28.0.0`.

Any ideas to implement centered normal looking TextInputEditText?

Comment: Use hint on `TextInputLayout` instead of `TextInputEditText`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede it's not working, looks the same

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), starting from the version `1.2.0-alpha02` the collapsed label position is determined via the edit text `gravity`.

Using something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:hint="@string/...."
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:gravity="center"
        ../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: It is not working when I set `app:hintEnabled="false"` or `app:boxBackgroundMode="none" ` to `TextInputLayout`

Comment: @KuvonchbekYakubov It is quite clear. Using `app:hintEnabled="false"`the layout's floating label is **disabled** and it means that there **isn't** the collapsed label. Using `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"` the text input area is not drawn as a box. It means that there **isn't** an outlined box.

Answer (score 1):

Centered Text inside an outlined textfield isn't really a case we support. It's not actually mentioned at all in the guidance (https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html)

It does look like a bug that the label text is centered when center gravity is applied. The easiest way to get that fixed would be to send a pr to us with the fix on https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android. Or you can file a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=439535.

Comment: Is this still the case? Are centered TextInputLayouts ever going to be supported in a later version of Material Design?