# TextInputLayout with OutlinedBox stroke overlaps the hint

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I use `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0` and trying to make EditText with outlined box with a hint. My issue is that stroke of the box is overlaps the hint:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
        app:hintEnabled="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/export_csv_sep_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="130dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:digits=",;:.|/*-_"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoFullscreen|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=","
            android:hint="@string/separator"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font_size"
            android:completionThreshold="1"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Is it bug in the material library, or something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends by the use of `android:gravity="center"`

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
   android:gravity="center"
   ..>
```

[Starting from `1.2.0-alpha02`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58970239/2016562) the bug is fixed and there is a different behavior.

In any case use `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` or `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` (there is an auto-inflation of `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` using `AutoCompleteTextView`).

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .....
    />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are quite some bugs with version `1.1.0`

For now they have addressed some in the latest release, update your version to latest one ([see latest releases here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases))

For now latest release is : `1.2.0-alpha06`

Or use below in your app gradle :
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06`

[Refer here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues) for issues reported for material components or you can raise one yourselves