# Vertically centering TextInputLayout text with no hint enabled

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

So I am trying to ensure that the main text in a `TextInputEditText` (wrapped in a `TextInputLayout`) is vertically centered with the default `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` style but when the hint is disabled.

As you can see in the image, with `app:hintEnabled="false"`, the current text is not vertically centred.

For reference I am  using the 1.1.0 version of the material components library.

My layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        app:hintEnabled="false">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/set_pos_password_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:text="1111"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

Try to set padding for TextInputEditText, it worked for me

```
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
```

Comment: This actually (and strangely ) works !!

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the bottom padding in your TextInputEditText style.

1. Set a custom themeOverlay in your TextInputLayout style
2. Use a custom style in `editTextStyle` theme attribute which inherits from
3. `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox`
   by default `FilledBox` style applies the following default padding:

```xml
 <item name="android:paddingTop">28dp</item>
 <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
```

You can read more from the [Material](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields) docs about text field theming.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was hoping for a solution that would actually centre it instead of just adjusting the padding until it seems right, this solution seems a little hacky unless I am missing something?

Comment: Have you tried adding the gravity attribute to the custom editTextStyle?

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58970239/12930265)  to a similar question.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the gravity does not have an effect. Also that answer you referenced seems to provide a solution to centre horizontally with a label, whereas I want it centred vertically and without a label.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example to achieve that. I assume the problem why the suggestions did not work yet are that you did apply the padding to the `TextInputLayout` and not to the nested `TextInputEditText`. The following definition will take car of this.

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.MyStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="2"
        android:text="10" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Style definition**

```
<!-- Define a style 
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.MyStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.MyStyle</item>
    <item name="expandedHintEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="hintEnabled">false</item>
    <!-- below is optional -->
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">4dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">4dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">4dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">4dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.MyStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.MyStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.MyStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense">
    <!-- equal padding will center the text -->
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4dp</item>
    <item name="singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

use layout_gravity = "Center".

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately this does not seem to vertically centre the text, I have tried to apply the attribute on both the outer ```TextInputLayout``` and the ```TextInputEditText```.

Comment: Please consider providing a code snippet or an example along with your rather short explanation.