# How to horizontally center "Label hint" in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

[Image of textinputlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTtAJ.png)

In the above image how can I horizontally center the "Label" ?

Comment: You can use this, maybe it's your answer ?

https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/296c80a4-0750-4a93-b40c-eed1749ce93d/y

Comment: ^That's scraped from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413119/outlinedbox-textinputlayout-and-gravity-center. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/inputAddress"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:hint="@string/postal_address"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    >

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtAddress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="adas"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```